# splitting a string in ruby 1.9.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I  have a string something like this

```
JINSAL0056(  1), JINSAL0057(  1), JINSAL0041(  1),
```

I need to put JINSAL0056, JINSAL0057,JINSAL0041 in a field and number inside the ().
I have written couple of codes let me know if I am going in the right directions.

```
s = "JINSAL0056(  1), JINSAL0057(  1), JINSAL0041(  1)"
ss = s.split(",")
sss = ss.split(" ( ")
```

How to write the split. Please do help me put

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass regexes to split too:

```
foo = "JINSAL0056(  1), JINSAL0057(  1), JINSAL0041(  1),"
foo.split(/[\(\),\s]+/)
```

The result:

```
["JINSAL0056", "1", "JINSAL0057", "1", "JINSAL0041", "1"]
```

And make it into a hash:

```
Hash[*foo.split(/[\(\),\s]+/)]
```

Which will give you:

```
{"JINSAL0056"=>"1", "JINSAL0057"=>"1", "JINSAL0041"=>"1"}
```

Comment: I believe that `/[^\w]+/` is enough in the case.

Comment: @iain Thanks a lot. But I wanna assign JINSAL0056 to a variable and 1 to a different variable. How do I do it

Answer (score 4):

I think you can try. (Not the best way of course.)

```
yourstring = "JINSAL0056(  1), JINSAL0057(  1), JINSAL0041(  1),"
yourstring.split(/(\w+)\(\s*(\d)\)[,\s*]/)
```

Result will be

```
["", "JINSAL0056", "1", " ", "JINSAL0057", "1", " ", "JINSAL0041", "1"]
```

but I recommended to use scan(//)

```
yourstring.scan(/(\w+)\(\s*(\d)\)[,\s*]/)
```

Result will be

```
[["JINSAL0056", "1"], ["JINSAL0057", "1"], ["JINSAL0041", "1"]]
```

to assign variable you can loop like this

```
yourstring.scan(/(\w+)\(\s*(\d)\)[,\s*]/).each do |a,b|
     puts "#{a} #{b}"
end
```

Comment: Like the `scan` version, but it probably should be `\s*` and not `\s+`, because it looks like there's room for 2-digit numbers like `ABC(12)`.

Comment: @Jirapong I was able to split it. Thanks a lot. But I wanna assign JINSAL0056 to a variable and 1 to a different variable. How do I do it

Answer (score 2):

```
s = "JINSAL0056(  1), JINSAL0057(  1), JINSAL0041(  1)"
res = s.split(', ').map{|line| line.chop.split('(  ')}
p res # [["JINSAL0056", "1"], ["JINSAL0057", "1"], ["JINSAL0041", "1"]]

res.each do |jinsal, number|
  puts "Do something with #{jinsal} and #{number}"
end
```